# Enable SPFx Command Extension on a document inside a Document Set

Tags: spfx, document-set, command-set

I have created a SPFx command extension for document libraries and it is visible and works fine for the documents inside the document library.

But when I create a document set inside document library, it is not available / visible there. It seems that the modern UI command bar itself is not available while I am inside document set (document set welcome page). It shows the classic UI Ribbon bar.

Is it possible to add the command set extension to the command bar / context menu for the documents inside a document set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I wrote an article to help others. Please check the link below.

https://mnaveedblog.wordpress.com/2018/09/19/enable-modern-sharepoint-view-for-a-document-set-in-sharepoint-online/